# C++ equivalent to java.nio.channels.Selector

Tags: c++, sockets

Does C++ have an equivalent to [java.nio.channels.Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) **or** some alternative mechanism?

Comment: What does `java.nio.channels.Selector` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) in C\C++ that you can use (Linux).

Also in [Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

They're both pretty much the same and the man page has an example, and more can be found online.

Comment: I'd suggest poll or epoll rather than select

Comment: select is defined on both Windows and *nix, while poll and epoll are *nix only I believe.

Comment: Windows Vista and above has its own version of poll():  WSAPoll()